# does an adjective imply the existence of the opposite

Tags: comparisons

does an adjective imply the existence of the opposite ?

Like: 
You're tall.

Does that mean that there is someone shorter than the tall person ? 
I think that at least one person has to exist which is shorter, to tell someone that he is tall.

Sorry English is not my mother language. Hopemyou guys understand what I mean.

Comment: It suggests but does not demand that there is an "opposite".

Comment: This question isn't really specific to English.

Comment: I ball can be red. Is some respects, green is the opposite of red (opponent process color theory, or the reason why you don't have red-green clothes, no matter how diverse and extensive your wardrobe). If you consider red and green opposites, then yes. If not, then no.

Comment: This is a question that might belong in philosophy.se. Can there be light without dark?  That sort of thing ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question of philosophy.

Comment: @KannE Does an adjective imply the existence of a counterpart? That's philosophy of language. At least it was when I took that class in college ...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps sometimes, but certainly not always.

> The shape is ***circular***.

What would the *opposite* of the adjective *circular* be? Square, triangular, or some other shape? I think at best it would be *not circular*—but that's pretty broad and undefined.

---

If you're going to assume an opposite, it could only be possible where a definitive opposite could possibly exist. There are adjectives that simply don't have opposites.

So, to turn opposition into some kind of grammatical or semantic rule, barring any context, would be a mistake.

Comment: To add to this answer, this example implies there is something which is not circular, but such a thing wouldn't necessarily be the opposite of circular. The same is true of tall: it implies something else is not tall, but it doesn't imply the existence of an opposite. I've heard children who discover opposites say things like "cat is the opposite of dog" because they assume everything has an opposite, but it doesn't.